# how to validate checkbox value in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

i will like a little help with the validation process i have using a checkbox.
i got 2 problems:

problem 1: 
i am successfully displaying a checkbox item on my screen ("f_mark"), but i need the checkbox get displayed as marked. actually the checkbox appear, but unchecked (not marked).
here is my code..

```
   sys.HTP.p(
   '<tr><td class="left"><a href="javascript:popUp2('''||apex_util.prepare_url('f?p=&APP_ID.:2:'||:app_session||':ADD:::P2_codigo_articulo:'||sys.htf.escape_sc(c1.codigo_articulo))||''',''700'',''400'');">' || 
   '<input type="text" size="12" name="f_unit_price" value="' || TRIM(TO_CHAR(c1.precio,'999G999G990'))  || '" readonly></td>' || 
   '<td><input type="number" size="6" value="' || c1.cantidad_existencia || '" name="f_qty" min="1" max="9999" step="1"</td>' ||
   '<td><input type="text" name="f_serie" value="' || c1.numero_serie || '" readonly></td>' || 
   '<td class="left">' ||  sys.HTF.escape_sc(c1.descripcion_articulo) || '</a></td>' || 
   '<td><input type="checkbox" name="f_mark" value="true"></td>' ||
   '<td><input type="text" name="f_prod_id" size="1" value="' || sys.HTF.escape_sc(c1.codigo_articulo)  || '" readonly></td>' || 
   '</tr>');
```

Problem 2:
i need to capture the value of the checkbox field ("f_mark") and make validations if the checkbox is checked. here is my code but it does not work.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
    <title>Totalizar</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#Calculate").click(
        // mueve el valor al campo de cantidad
        function () {
            var total = 0;
            var total_qty = 0;


           $("input[name=f_mark]").each(
                function () {
                    var marcado = $(this).val();
                    var quantity = $(this).parents('tr').find("input[name=f_qty]").val();
                    var productId = $(this).parents('tr').find("input[name=f_prod_id]").val();
                    if (marcado == 'true') {
                        var price   = $(this).parents('tr').find("input[name=f_unit_price]").val();
                        var serieId = $(this).parents('tr').find("input[name=f_serie]").val();
                        var prodtotal = (quantity * price);
                        total = total + prodtotal;
                        total_qty = total_qty + 1;
                    }
                }
            );
            $('#printHere').html(decimalizer(total));
            $('#printHereqty').html(total_qty);
        }
    );
```

thanks in advance for any tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.** Check the box

`<input type="checkbox" name="f_mark" value="true" checked="checked" />`

**2.** Test the box

```
$("input[name=f_mark]").each(   
  if (this.checked) ...
```

or

`$("input[name=f_mark]:checked").each(`

or

```
if ($(this).is(":checked"))...
```

Comment: looks very logic. i will try it in a momment when come back to my office.

Answer (score 0):

Problem 1: Add the checked attribute on the input

```
<input type="checkbox" name="f_mark" value="true" checked>
```

Proble 2: you can check if checkbox is checked

```
if ($('input[name="f_mark"]').is(':checked')) {}
```

Comment: looks very logic. i will try it in a momment when come back to my office.